# CSS: Position DIV at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

This is a sample HTML page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="content"> 
    </div>
    <footer>&nbsp;</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my style sheet:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  width:  8cm;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff0;
  height: 15cm;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: How the code is rendered.]

My problem is that I want the red footer to be at the bottom of the page (not the bottom of the viewport), assuming that the `.content` is of an variable height actually. Is that possible without JavaScript?

Comment: Do you mean `footer {position: fixed;}`?

Comment: @sdcr No, as I wrote explicitly, I *do not want* the footer to stay at the bottom of the viewport, but at the bottom of the page, i.e. the body.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you use `position:absolute` on both content and footer?

Comment: @sdct: Thanks, sometimes the solution is that simple. Remove the `position: absolute` from the content helped :) Actually it was a fix for some other problem I experienced but this is a different topic.

Answer (score 2):

[This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4928y65/1/) shows a footer that is always either at the *lowest point on the page* or on the *bottom of the viewport*.

The DIV is positioned at the bottom of the viewport when the content does not fill the page, and stays below the content when the content gets taller than the viewport.

To accomplish this, use a `min-height` on the `body` like this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Tested in Safari 8.0.3.

Comment: This doesn't work with `position: absolute` on my `content` or your `main`, tested with Chrome and Firefox. I need that `position: absolute` because I need to position the content relatively to its parent.

Comment: That is because if you use `position: absolute` on the content, no space will be reserved for it at all. You need to find another workaround if removing the `position: absolute` from the content is not an option.